# Setup standalone with all the data from cluster, mongodb

Tags: replication, mongodb

I have a mongo cluster with 3 nodes(a primary, a secondary, and an arbitrary) with replication enabled for primary and secondary. For some reason would like to take down the cluster and have a standalone instance(in arbitrary). Since data is not available in arbitrary, have copied data from cluster nodes to the path(/data/db). Removed the replication factor in mongod.conf and started mongo instance. But couldn't see the databases. What else is required? OR do I have to get mongo-dump and mongo-restore? If so, doing so for 200GB is a costly and time-consuming process. Help me with this.

Comment: When you copied data from your replica set node (not cluster, replica set) there was local database where there is still information that, this node (IP-address; hostname) is arbiter. That's why you don't see databases there. Look 'local' databases collections and remove not needed, like replset.* and system.replset

Comment: @srikanth, What is MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Answer (score 1):

As per MongoDB documentation [Replica Set Arbiter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-arbiter/) An arbiter does not have a copy of data set and cannot become a primary. Replica sets may have arbiters to add a vote in [elections for primary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-elections/#replica-set-elections). Arbiters always have exactly 1 election vote, and thus allow replica sets to have an uneven number of voting members without the overhead of an additional member that replicates data.

> Changed in version 3.6: Starting in MongoDB 3.6, arbiters have
>   priority 0. When you upgrade a replica set to MongoDB 3.6, if the
>   existing configuration has an arbiter with priority 1, MongoDB 3.6
>   reconfigures the arbiter to have priority 0.

**Primary with a Secondary and an Arbiter**

A three member replica set with a two members that store data has:

One [primary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-primary/).
One [secondary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-secondary/) member. The secondary can become primary in an [election](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-elections/).
One [arbiter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-arbiter/). The arbiter only votes in elections.

[image]
Since the arbiter does not hold a copy of the data, these deployments provides only one complete copy of the data. Arbiters require fewer resources, at the expense of more limited redundancy and fault tolerance.